# How to Retrieve Specific number of records from Table in Interbase 6.0

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-2010, interbase

I am using **Interbase 6.0** for my Delphi Application. I need to get top 10 (for example) records from a table. But **TOP** keyword feature is availble in **Interbase 7**. Is there any way to achieve this, kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upgrade to v.7?

Comment: Better to Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROWS clause, here's an example:

```
SELECT SALESMAN, SALES_DOLLARS, SALES_REGION
FROM SALESPEOPLE
ORDER BY SALES_DOLLARS DESC
ROWS 1 TO 50;
```

In this case, only the first 50 rows whill be returned.

Comment: The `rows`clause is introduced in Interbase 6.5 far as I know.